# Principal Ideal Domains

Tags: ring-theory

[image]

I'm trying to teach myself by doing questions. I understand the definition of a ideal is a multiplicatively closed additive subgroup of a ring. And a principal ideal means it has a generator 'g'. So from this I guess the integers have a principal ideal domain. Where I'm stuck is the three polynomial examples and the reasons why so I can learn and apply in other circumstances.

Edit: For part a, I'm really looking for like a rule of thumb of picking out principal ideal domains if there is one.

As for part b, I really do have no idea and just looking for general help.

Very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you first try it for the intersection of only two ideals? For example, what is $\;4\Bbb Z\cap9\Bbb Z\;$ ? You need elements that are **both** a multiple of $\;4\;$ and a multiple of $\;9\;$ ...After this, perhaps (b) will be easier to attack.

Comment: Yeh b) does seem okay. Its mainly the reasons for part a that I'm struggling with. Thanks.

Comment: Well, any polynomial ring over a *field* is a PID, and that makes the first and fourth rings in (a) a PID each. The second one is famously **not** a PID, for example: check that the ideal $\;\langle 2,x\rangle\le\Bbb Z[x]\;$ cannot be generated by one single element (integer polynomial). The third ring in that part is easier to see it is not a PID...can you think of a rather easy ideal that is not principal?

Answer (score 1):

For the polynomial examples, note that in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ the ideal $(X,Y)$ isn't principal.

Also, $\mathbb{Z}_{2011}$ is a field, and $F[X]$ is a PID if and only if $F$ is a field.

For b), note that $(a) \cap (b)$ is generated by the single element $d$, where $d$= g.c.d of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How do you know its a field? Is there a quick way of telling? And the other polynomials why would you discount them? I'm looking for like a rule of thumb for a question like this.

Comment: @user140152: $2011$ is a prime. $Z_p$ is a field if and only if $p$ is a prime. Also, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain

Comment: Does this stay true for polynomials?

Comment: @user140152: yes. Have a look at the wikipedia entry.